# How to reupload images to a Facebook album from Aperture?

Tags: apple-aperture, facebook

If I upload some pictures in a new Facebook album and after that I need to adjust them, I select the picture from Facebook's album in aperture but when is the picture reuploaded to Facebook? Does it do it automatically or is there a commando to force the process?

And other question, there is a way to know if an image is already on a Facebook album? Now I need to add some other photos from the same project and maybe I don't remember if it's already in it!

#### Update

I made myself a way to recognize the pics that are already uploaded on facebook's album....I tagged them with a blue (fb style :)) label!

Comment: What do you mean by theme? Facebook just lets you upload images to your profile/albums, there is no theme.

Comment: Sorry, misspelled, it's them!

Comment: So I gather your two questions are: 1.If you make adjustments in Aperture after previously uploading photos to Facebook, will the photos update automatically on Facebook or is there a way to update them? 2.Does Aperture mark photos as already on Facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you create a Facebook album in Aperture it will show up on the left hand pane or project inspector area. **To re-upload or sync any changes that you have made, simply click the "publish" icon** to the right of the album title.

I found a handy tutorial on Youtube that might help you with this process: [here](http://youtu.be/djSwErVnkVw).

There is not a built in feature that specifically notes if an image is on Facebook that I am aware of. You will have to just look at the albums in the project inspector area and see if the images are in the Facebook albums there.